# How to use select statement in iterate in IBATIS?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, ibatis

MySQL query is as follow

```
update  group_entity set deleted = 1  where entity_id in (select entity_id from entity where entity_row_id in ('1-424g','1-242T') and entity_type='Data');
```

this query is working in mysql.

my Ibatis query with changes is as follow

```
<update id="updateData" parameterClass="abc.data.updateDataParameters">
    update group_entity set deleted = 1 where entity_id in
    <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
        select entity_id from entity where entity_row_id in
         <iterate property="parentIds" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
            #parentIds[]#
        </iterate>
        and entity_type = #parentType#
    </iterate>
</update>
```

But Ibatis query is not working getting Error **ParameterObject or property was not a Collection, Array or Iterator.**
Error:

```
--- Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: ParameterObject or property was not a Collection, Array or Iterator.; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
```

Please tell me how do i use select statement in iterate like `<iterate>Select id from table</iterate>` which returning list of id.

My updateDataParameters

```
class updateDataParameters
{
List<String> parentId;
string parentType;
// with getter and setter and receptive constructor  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First iterate element is not necessary.
Your request should be:

```
<update id="updateData" parameterClass="abc.data.updateDataParameters">
    update group_entity set deleted = 1 where entity_id in (
        select entity_id from entity where entity_row_id in
        <iterate property="parentId" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
            #parentId[]#
        </iterate>
        ) and entity_type = #parentType#
</update>
```

There is also a typo mistake: parentIds should be parentId to match class attribute.